# RoR: Basic foreign key question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a a simple lookup table. When I display an `agency` I would like to display the `locality.name` rather than the `locality_id`. The `Locality.name` is stored in the `locality` table. Just the `id` is stored in the `agency` table.

Below shows the `locality_id`, I would like for it to show the `locality_name` instead.

How do I do this?

agency controller

```
def index
  @agencies = Agency.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @agencies }
  end
end
```

agency index

```
<% @agencies.each do |agency| %>
  <p>
    <b>Agency:</b>
    <%=h @agency.agency %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Locality:</b>
    <%=h @agency.locality_id %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Again, I know this is a basic question so I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it in your view.

```
<% @agencies.each do |agency| %>

<p>
<b>Agency:</b>
<%=h @agency.agency %>
</p>

<p>
<b>Locality:</b>
<%=h @agency.locality.name %> <!-- this will bomb out if there agencies that 
                                   don't have a locality - if that's an issue, 
                                   add "if @agency.locality" to the end. -->
</p>
<% end %>
```